# How to use @datetime function in telegram instant view?

Tags: view, telegram, instant

I am trying to set up a telegram Instant View. I am facing problem with the function datetime `@datetime`, I've looked at the [official documentation](https://instantview.telegram.org/docs#).

I have the following date `Jul 19, 2018 at 2:25pm`. In case we are on the same year of the date, the string won't contain the year ex: `Jul 19 at 2:25pm` means 19 July of this year. How can I deal with the missing year?

This is my code so far.

```
@datetime(-2, "en-US", "LLL d 'at' k:mm"): "Jan 25 at 2:44pm"
published_date: $@

#manage the current year case
@datetime(0, "en-US", "LLL d, YYYY 'at' k:mma"): "Jan 25, 2018 at 2:44pm"
published_date: $@
```

As of now the missing year is not properly managed. In this way the year is always 1970.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm is following:

1. Try to parse the date with `YYYY` inside
2. If failing, the `$pubslished_date` will contain 0 or some garbage (try to `@debug` it). So you can use something like `@if_not( $published_date ) { ... }`, where you can try to parse the date without `YYYY`. Don't forget to force redefine the variable with `published_date!: …`.

If that won't work, try to play with conditional binding: `pubslihed_date?: …`. It has the same logic. (Just to put a question mark `?` in the second binding in your current code).